# Require one field or the other but CANNOT be left blank

Tags: jquery

I am looking for the following functionality:

The user is required to fill in either one of two fields to be able to submit. (e.g. There is a phone number field and an email field and the user must fill in at least 1 to leaves some sort of contact details.)

How can do I possibly do this through jquery? Forgive me as I am relatively new to jquery and am still learning.

I was thinking along the lines of the validate function but any way to get my desired result would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($.trim($('#field1').val())!=="" || $.trim($('#field1').val())!=="" ) {
    // you're okay
} else {
    // both of them are blank
}
```

You need to test for (non-)equivalence to a blank string, or else entering the value `0` will be evaluated as false.

Comment: Those should be `!==`, OP wants at least one to be non blank

Comment: What if neither of them are filled in (or both are filled in)?

Comment: What if its between an image upload field and choosing from a radio list? Can that affect how you approach it?

Comment: @Rocket OP didn't seem to need an exclusive-or.

Comment: @wiseman7687 Yes, it can. But that's a different question altogether.

Comment: Well I edited my post to clarify but basically a User has an option to either upload an image OR choose an existing image from a sql queried radio list. I want to just add some sort of prevention so that it WONT submit if both fields are blank. BUT one or the other is ok.

Comment: @wiseman7687 It's not really fair for you to completely change the question after it's been answered. Please submit that as a new question and accept an answer for this one.

Comment: I will accept an answer though I do feel that this is similar to what I want.. Is it not?

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = $('input[type=text]').filter(function(index){
    return $.trim(this.val()) != '';
}).length > 0;

if(valid) {
   $('#myForm').submit();
}
```